# Dealing with cumbersome string.Split overloads?

Tags: c#

The string.Split() in .NET can be cumbersome to use.  With many overloads you must specify an array even when passing a single delimiter (in fact only one overload is marked with params).

Is there any such alternative? Is there a way of accomplishing the task without creating arrays.

Comment: Although you do still end up creating an array, you can do something like `"x".ToCharArray()` (where *x* is the split delimiter) which makes things a little less painful.

Comment: @CraigW. Good point, incorporated into answer.

Comment: For many of the overloads the array param is marked 'params'. This means you can just go split('x')

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that there are two conflicting best practices in developing such an API(they are both good practices and usually do not conflict except in this particular case):

- Only `params` parameter can/*must* appear as the last parameter.
- Overloads of a function *should* maintain the same parameter ordering.

So you have the first overload:

```
Split(params char[] separator)
```

Which leverages the `params` keyword so that you don't explicitly need to create an array as that is done implicitly.

The other overloads follow the second guideline, maintaining the `separator` parameter as the first parameter, but therefore cannot specify the `params` keyword since that can only appear on the last parameter.

So it's a design choice balanced between the two best practices.  In this case, they followed the maintain-parameter-order guideline, and did not use the `params` keyword on the other overloads because it is not allowed when it is followed by others parameters.

### Solution

You could implement your own static methods or extensions where the `separator` parameter is always the last parameter, and therefore can always specify `params` with it.  Basically you could make the decision to favor the first guideline and disregard the second:

```
public string[] Split(int count, StringSplitOptions options, params char[] separator)
```

You have to be careful when versioning class libraries and evolving APIs.  There are scenarios where introduction of a new `params` overload will allow it to match old overloads ambiguously and break the code of projects consuming it.

### Alternative

If you want to avoid writing overload extensions, as [Craig W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97382/craig-w) points out `"x".ToCharArray()` might be a more intuitive way to generate the single item array(or even `"xyz".ToCharArray()` for multiple single character delimiters).  Should note that this means you are adding a bit of extra runtime processing but it is probably so small to be negligible.

Comment: I think you're probably right about the reason, but there are many places in .NET where optional parameters with "weird" types occur in the middle of a parameter list.  As such, I would argue that one could honor the first requirement without violating the second.

Comment: @supercat Yes, optional parameters with weird types can occur in the middle(granted all following parameters are optional).  However, we are talking about `params` keyword though which is different than an optional parameter.  `params` cannot appear in the middle, and can only be used at the end.

Comment: Yes, but since the options are all "weird" types (i.e. special-purpose enumerations), I would think they could have been put before the list of separators while leaving it as a `params` keyword, and I would further posit that doing so would not have violated the "same ordering" expectation.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an (extension) method that had optional parameters.

```
public static string[] SplitDelimiter(this string str, char delimiter, int count = 0, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
{
    int toCount = count == 0 ? count = str.Length : toCount = count;
    return str.Split(new[] { delimiter }, toCount, options);
}
```

Then you can use it without creating an array explicitly.

```
string myString = "1,2,3";
Console.WriteLine(myString.SplitDelimiter(',').Count()); //returns 3
```